# issue with float from argv

Tags: python, argv

I'm having a hard time converting a passed in argv[1] to a float number. I have been trying to basically pass in any int followed by a decimal and have it round up/down to the nearest whole number. (basic starter python project) I have been trying to play with float for a bit now and just cant figure it out.

```
import sys

x = int(sys.argv[1])
num = x + .5
s = str(num())
point = s.find('.')
print s[:point]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

Edit(current code, after coffee and cleanup):

```
import sys

def x(argument):
    num = argument + .5
    s = str(num())
    point = s.find('.')
    print s[:point]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x(int(round(float(sys.argv[1]))))
```

Finalized code(credit goes to: NPE)

```
import sys

def x(argument):
    print "Passed in value: " + str(argument)
    num = argument + .5
    print "Rounded whole number: " + str(int(num))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x(float(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: Are you expecting `x` to be a function?

Comment: No, I don't think I need it to be a function per say more of just the passed in value if possible.

Comment: You are not making much sense. What do you expect `x(..)` to do in `__main__`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for either

```
val = round(float(sys.argv[1]))
```

or

```
val = int(round(float(sys.argv[1])))
```

depending on what you're expecting the type of `val` to be.

Comment: Actually thanks to you I have been able to clean up the code and realized that I hadn't passed in an argument. Im still having issue with float point since it isn't able to be passed into the int argument for what ever reason. Though you have me playing around with a lot of permutations. In the least I think you came close to fixing my issue! Thank you very very much, sorry for the noob questions.

Comment: Was actually able to solve it thanks to you. I omitted the int from the function passed in and had it print it as a int later on in the code. Thank you for your help.